# Convert a String to Date and compare it with LocalDateTime.now() in Java

Tags: java, android, date, compare

The String data is in a file stored earlier in the format "Mon Jan 08 18:55:57 GMT+05:30 2024". I have used the following code to convert the String to get a value of "08 Jan 2024"

```
Boolean goahead = false;
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat formatterOut = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
try {
  pundate = formatter.parse(punchDate);
  System.out.println(pundate);
  System.out.println(formatterOut.format(pundate));
} catch (ParseException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}

String convertedtodaydate = dateFormater(String.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now()), "dd MMM yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd"); //Output is 16 Feb 2024

try {
   if(Objects.requireNonNull(sdf.parse(convertedtodaydate)).after(sdf.parse(formatterOut.format(pundate)))) {
     goahead = true;
   }
  } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

The error I get is

```
W/System.err: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "16 Feb 2024"
```

Is there a simpler way to check whether the Stored date is older than the current date?

Comment: why convert to `Date` instead of `LocalDateTime`? In particular since you already want to compare it to a `LocalDateTime`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Never use the terribly flawed legacy classes such as `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date`, `Calendar`. Use only *java.time* classes.

Never call `LocalDateTime.now`. I cannot imagine a scenario where that is the optimal choice. That class cannot represent a moment as it lacks the context of time zone or offset.

> String data is in a file stored earlier in the format "Mon Jan 08 18:55:57 GMT+05:30 2024".

Never store date-time values textually using localized formats. Use only [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats for data storage and data exchange.

Parse text using `DateTimeFormatter`.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss OOOO uuuu" ).withLocale( Locale.US ) ;
String input = "Mon Jan 08 18:55:57 GMT+05:30 2024" ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

You are interested in only the date portion.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate();
```

To generate text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, call `toString`.

```
String output = ld.toString() ;
```

To generate text in custom format, define another `DateTimeFormatter`.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd MMM uuuu" ).withLocale( Locale.US ) ;
String output = ld.format( f ) ;
```

You apparently want to compare the stored date to today’s date. To capture the current date, specify a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone. Tokyo Japan is in “tomorrow” while simultaneously Toledo Ohio is in “yesterday”.

```
ZoneId zKolkata = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
LocalDate todayKolkata = LocalDate.now( zKolkata ) ;
boolean isStoredDatePast = ld.isBefore( todayKolkata ) ;
```

Perhaps you really want to see if the stored moment is before the current moment.

```
boolean isStoredMomentPast = zdt.toInstant().isBefore( Instant.now() ) ;
```

To calculate elapsed time in hours-minutes-seconds, use `Duration`.

```
Duration elapsed = Duration.between ( zdt.toInstant() , Instant.now() ) ;
```

For elapsed time in years-months-days, use `Period`.

Comment: Excellent suggestion with all details. I have to use Locale.getDefault() as Locale.IN is still not available. Marking this as "The Answer". Thank you!! Do not understand why my question is downgraded.

Comment: @SNAD I imagine the down-vote and lack of up-votes is due to a lack of clarity in your Question. Notice how many topics I had to hit in my Answer, as I tried to follow along the meandering train of thoughts in your prose and in your code. In the future try to hone your question and code into a very focused pointed problem statement, with example input and desired output. Study existing highly up-voted Questions.

Comment: Sure @Basil Bourque. Thank you for your highly analytical method in answering my question.

Comment: *I have to use Locale.getDefault() as Locale.IN is still not available.* I'm wondering how that is relevant to the above..?

Comment: Can we get the "TimeSince" using this method? I have tried long diff = Instant.now().compareTo(zdt.toInstant()); which gives a value of "1"

Comment: @g00se Please look at the first DateTimeFormatter

Comment: `Duration timeSince = Duration.between(OffsetDateTime.parse(dateString, formatter), OffsetDateTime.now());`

Comment: Great. Worked like a charm. For the given dates, it gave "PT936H56M47.154S". I can ignore PT and process for my purposes. Thank you

Comment: Well, of course you can use the object's methods. I'm assuming you're interested more in the time diff than the date diff

Comment: @SNAD `Duration` has methods to access its parts, and to do math.